# How can I loop through each Record and see if any of 3 requirements are missing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I have a table with `ProducerName` and `ProducerRequirementsListID`

[image]

Each `ProducerName` supposed to have 3 requirements(1,2,3), but some of them might missing at least one of them: either 1, 2 or 3. 
So how can I catch unique `ProcucerName` that missing AT LEAST ONE of the `ProducerRequirementsListID`?

Ideally would be create 3 new columns `Req_1`,`Req_2` `Req_3` and for each unique `ProducerName` display `TRUE` or `FALSE`
Something like that:

[image]

Should I be using `WHILE` loop for operations like that?

Comment: No you definitely should NOT be using a loop for this. Looping is horrible inefficient and should be avoided with a very few exceptions, mostly mail merge or some administrative tasks.

Comment: I would urge you to normalize your structures here. Repeating the ProducerName over and over can become very problematic. What happens if you have more than 1 with the same name? Or what happens when you need to change the name because it was entered incorrectly? You have to update all the rows instead of 1 row in a Producer table.

Comment: Thanks #Sean. I agree with you. We are working on normalizing the structure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a pivot would be what you are looking for.  Simple self extracting example.  While Loops while useful should not be done as a first resort in SQL as it is result set based language and performance could be bad over time when doing in a while loop what could be done with a pivot.

```
DECLARE @People TABLE (PersonName VARCHAR(128), Ord INT);

INSERT INTO @People (PersonName, Ord) VALUES ('Brett', 1), ('Brett', 2), ('Brett', 3), ('Emily', 1), ('Emily', 2);

SELECT
    PersonName
, [1] as FirstValue
, [2] as SecondValue
, [3] as ThirdValue
From @People
    PIVOT ( Count(Ord) FOR Ord IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS piv
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: No prob, happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear that you're actually trying to get a pivot or you are looking only for `ProducerName` that are missing requirements. Assuming the latter, then all you need to do is group by and filter by `less than 3`. For example:

```
SELECT ProducerName
FROM Table
GROUP BY ProducerName
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

Comment: Got me by 60 seconds but just what i was thinking

Answer (score 1):

You can use a quick case statement....

```
select 
    ProducerName
    ,case when ProducerRequirementListID = 1 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Req1
    ,case when ProducerRequirementListID = 2 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Req2
    ,case when ProducerRequirementListID = 3 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Req3
from ProducerName
```

Here is a way to get just a list of the producers who are missing one...

```
select ProducerName
from ProducerTable
group by ProducerName
having count(ProducerName) < 3
```

Here's a better way, using test data from django, to find which one is missing...

```
select 
    ProducerName
    ,case 
        when sum(ProducerRequirementListID) = 3 then 3
        when sum(ProducerRequirementListID) = 4 then 2
        when sum(ProducerRequirementListID) = 5 then 1
        when sum(ProducerRequirementListID) = 6 then NULL
    end as MissingReq
from ProducerTable
group by ProducerName
```

**TEST DATA**

```
DECLARE @People TABLE (PersonName VARCHAR(128), Ord INT);

INSERT INTO @People (PersonName, Ord) VALUES ('Brett', 1), ('Brett', 2), ('Brett', 3), ('Emily', 1), ('Emily', 2), ('Jake', 1), ('Jake', 3);

SELECT 
    PersonName,
    case 
        when sum(Ord) = 4 then 2
        when sum(Ord) = 3 then 3
        when sum(Ord) = 5 then 1
        when sum(Ord) = 6 then NULL
    end as MissingReq
from @People
group by PersonName
```

Comment: Thanks #scsimon but some of the producers have more than one same requirements. `sum()` probably wont work here. But the idea is amazing. Thanks

Comment: @oleg no worries... i gave you two other solutions as well. meh.